# Communication with php fastcgi socket from ruby

Tags: php, ruby, sockets, fastcgi

I wish to check correct php fastcgi operation from a ruby script. Do do that, I just wanted to send a simple PHP script to the socket and check for the correct return value.

Now, I am new to both ruby and sockets, so I tried

```
require 'socket'

s = UNIXSocket.new("/var/run/php/php.socket")
s.send('<?php print "Hello World"; ?>', 0)
puts s.recv(11)
```

but I get

```
test.rb:5:in `recv': Connection reset by peer - recvfrom(2) (Errno::ECONNRESET)
          from test.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

Google is less than helpful, because 'PHP' triggers too many tutorials on how to use sockets from php.

I know that the php socket works correctly (since it powers my website).
How could I get my script to correctly receive "Hello World"?

Comment: Are you confirmed php generate any socket at give location `/var/run/php/php.socket` As personnaly I believe that php does not work as standalone server but work with web servers to accomplish this. For CLI it should not need socket also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FastCGI has a [binary protocol](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html) that you would need to implement. So in the end you'd better use a library that has already implemented it for you.

After all you might be better off by simply using a bash script and a program installed by the libfcgi library (`apt-get install libfcgi-dev` on Debian), for example

```
SCRIPT_FILENAME=/path/test.php cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /var/run/php/php.socket
```

(Jens corrected my original example for his environment in a comment, thanks)

Comment: This almost worked, thank you! Instead of piping the php code into cgi-fcgi you seem to have to pass a filename like `SCRIPT_FILENAME=/path/test.php cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /var/run/php/php.socket`

Comment: ah, I see. I only had a "php-fpm" for testing available, seems like it works differently there.